# how to check whether all the values of a database field are same using django queries

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

I have a model like below

```
Class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

So suppose we have `4 product` records in database, is there anyway to check whether all the 4 product records have the `same price` ?

I don't want to loop through all the products, because there may be `thousands` of product records in database, and doing so will become a performance issue.

So i am looking for something like using builtin django database ORM to do this

```
check_whether_all_the_product_records_has_same_price_value = some django ORM operation......

if check_whether_all_the_product_records_has_same_price_value:
    # If all the Product table records(four) has the same price value 
    # return the starting record
   return check_whether_product_has_same_price_value(0)
```

So can anyone please let me know how can we do this ?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this? Its going to slow down your site like crazy.

Comment: ohhhh, actually had some functionality which needs to check the above scenario and return a product based on the above scenario, and yeah ofcourse i had mentioned it will cause perfomance issues, so posted here to get an optimized solution if possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can propose You count lines using `filter`

```
if Product.objects.all().count() == Product.objects.filter(price=price).count():
    pass
```

or use `distinct`

```
if Product.objects.all().products.distinct('price').count() == 1:
    pass
```

Note that this example works correctly on Portgres only.

Also You can Use `annotate` to calculate count I think

```
if Product.objects.all().values('price').annotate(Count('price')).count() == 1:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct to find unique prices:

```
products = Product.objects.filter([some condition])
prices = products.values_list('price', flat=True).distinct()
```

Then check the length of prices.